# I mistakenly turn cascade delete to false. Now I want to set it to true again. How can I do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I mistakenly turn cascade delete to false and created the table. Now if I drop table then it will be very difficult for me to control dependent code on that table. How can I turn it on again? What will be the code for Fluent API? Let me know if there is any other way.

**See here my migaration**[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you configured the newly created table with optional relationship? Can you show `OnModelCreating` method contents too?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cascading, in the OnModelCreating method of context class like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AnyEntityName>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Customer)
                .WithMany(o => o.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

**Addtional info:**

Cascade delete automatically deletes dependent records or set null to foreignkey properties when the principal record is deleted.

Cascade delete is enabled by default in Entity Framework for all types of relationships such as one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.

**Source:**http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

**Useful Link:** http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/899/entity-framework-code-first-fluent-aspnet-mvc

Hope the above information was helpful

Comment: Have not use Fluent API yet. Will I have to add migration and update my database if I use fluent API?

Comment: yes you are correct  you have to add migration and update database